# CodeLite project exported from CMake doesn't compile

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, codelite

I am using CMake to generate a workspace with projects for CodeLite.
For that I'm using `CMAKE_CODELITE_USE_TARGETS` to make sure it creates my projects into multiple CodeLite projects. Unfortunately, it doesn't work correctly. When I generate my project with the flag, multiple projects are created, like I want. But only executables compile. Meaning, if a project is suposed to output a executable, it compiles fine. But if the project output's a shared library, it won't compile.

Now, when I disable my use target's flag mentioned above, it results in having only one project containing all targets, but it compiles file.(Shared and Executables are both compiled just fine)

So for some reason, target's that compile to a shared library don't compile with the use_target's flag, but the do without it.

Does anyone know what's the issue?

Thanks!

Edit:
I DO need the multi_target's flag btw, without it, I can't debug my program as all executable will become one project.

Edit2:
Some clarification:
When I right click the (shared lib)project, and press Build. It simply won't do anything. And when I set the shared lib project as default project, and press Build on the top of the screen. The IDE just crashes.

Comment: "it won't compile" - so what exactly happens in this case&

Comment: @VTT It's simply won't compile. When I right click the (shared lib)project, and press Build. It simply won't do anything. And when I set the shared lib project as default project, and press Build on the top of the screen. The IDE just crashes.